# NASM 'org' directive with '-fobj'

Tags: compiler-errors, syntax-error, nasm, object-files

Why doesn't NASM compile to an object file with the org directive?

```
org 0x7C00
nop
mov ax, ax
nop
```

If I compile this with:

```
nasm -O0 -fobj temp.asm
```

NASM gives me an error for whatever reason:

```
temp.asm:1: error: parser: instruction expected
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case instead of `org` you should use `resb`:

```
; file: nasmOrg.asm
; assemble: nasm -f obj nasmOrg.asm -o nasmOrg.obj

SEGMENT _TEXT PUBLIC CLASS=CODE USE16

;        resb    0x0100 ; reserve 0x0100 bytes for a .COM program
        resb    0x7C00 ; reserve 0x7C00 bytes for a boot sector
..start:
nop
mov ax, ax
nop
```

This is how you can compile different parts of a .COM program into separate object files. If you use TLINK as the linker, the next step would be:

> tlink.exe /t nasmOrg.obj [any other object files], nasmOrg.bin

Note that if you omit the comma and the following name of the resultant binary (nasmOrg.bin) or if you specify a name with the .COM extension (e.g. nasmOrg.com), TLINK will refuse to link, it will say something like:

> Error: Cannot generate COM file : invalid initial entry point address

And you'll have to change 0x7C00 to 0x0100 to make a .COM program.

Comment: I realize that this is a really old thread, but I am trying to do this exact same thing. I would like to create an object file instead of a .com file because I want to use the `-g` option for NASM to have debugging information in Turbo Debugger. So in your example, after linking my object file (`hello.obj`), how would I get the .com file?

Comment: @wkjagt Using tlink exactly or almost exactly as shown? What did you try and what did you get?

Comment: Oh I just found the cause, but without understanding why. What made it work was changing my `start` label to `..start`. There must be some meaning to the double dot?

Comment: @wkjagt See the NASM documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `-obj` option will output the assembled file in [Object Module Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocatable_Object_Module_Format).  Using the `org` directive is only supported in binary format [accoring to the manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html) .

The reason for this is that the linker should handle relocations for you.

If you want to create free space, maybe the `times` directive will help you:

```
times 10   db 0    ; 10 zero bytes
```

Comment: On wikipedia, it says: "There are no file offsets (like a pointer to a symbol table) in the file. Therefore a linker must parse all entries (records) of the object file to get information about it." Is that what your are talking about?

Comment: @ColeJohnson No. That sentence is about creating executable files. You  probably want to omit the `-fobj` option if you want to create a bootloader (or see the other response).